# Slow Performance for multiple requests in RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have started using AWS RDS MYSQL for my use-case.

I am using RDS to store the user uploaded server information from a website.

I have tested uploading 1 file with 500 records; took 20 seconds. Again for testing, I have uploaded 9 files simultaneously with a total of 500 records; took 55 seconds.

I don't know what is the possible reason for this? I am using db.t3.large instance.

Which RDS metric do I need to look after or which Performance Insights metrics?

Is this the issue due to lesser baseline I/O performance of the gp2 volume?

Comment: What do you mean by "upload?"  Be specific as to the command/utility/program you are using.

Comment: In my case, "upload" means adding new Item in the database Table.

Comment: Again, that is not specific at all.  Do you have a client program written in some language like python or php?  What does the code look like?

Comment: it is simple MYSQL query to insert data into the RDS Database Table.

Comment: Your question does not have enough information to help you with anything.  It is too general and you are avoiding specifics.  A large RDS instance should have more than enough capacity to insert 500 rows whether in batches of 50 or whatever number.  Using for example, phpMyAdmin, I can create a sample authors table and perform 600 inserts in under 1 second.  I can paste the same series into an ssh terminal with a mysql command line session open, and it will take 10 seconds or less.  Without details there is nothing much more anyone can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following metrics:

- Write IOPS (Count/Second)
- Write Latency (Milliseconds)
- Network Receive Throughput

Are you running the operation over the internet or within the VPC? There should be some network latency if you are using the internet.

Comment: Yes, I am running the operation over the internet. But, I am asking about when I send 500 records at one file, then it took 20 seconds, but when split these 500 records into 9 files and uploaded simultaneously, then it took 55 seconds but from my expectation, it should be completed in the same 20 second.